# Set last non-zero element of each row to zero - NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I have an array A:

```
A = array([[1, 2, 3,4], [5,6,7,0] , [8,9,0,0]])
```

I want to change the last non-zero of each row to 0

```
A = array([[1, 2, 3,0], [5,6,0,0] , [8,0,0,0]])
```

how to write the code for any n*m  numpy array?
Thanks, S ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1**

One approach based on `cumsum` and `argmax` -

```
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),(A!=0).cumsum(1).argmax(1)] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [59]: A
Out[59]: 
array([[2, 0, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 0],
       [8, 9, 0, 0]])

In [60]: A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),(A!=0).cumsum(1).argmax(1)] = 0

In [61]: A
Out[61]: 
array([[2, 0, 3, 0],
       [5, 6, 0, 0],
       [8, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Approach #2**

One more based on `argmax` and hopefully more efficient -

```
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),A.shape[1] - 1 - (A[:,::-1]!=0).argmax(1)] = 0
```

---

**Explanation**

One of the uses of `argmax` is to get ID  of the **first** occurence of the `max` element along an axis in an array . In the first approach we get the cumsum along the rows and get the first max ID, which represents the last non-zero elem. This is because `cumsum` on the leftover elements won't increase the sum value after that last non-zero element.

Let's re-run that case in a bit more detailed manner -

```
In [105]: A
Out[105]: 
array([[2, 0, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 0],
       [8, 9, 0, 0]])

In [106]: (A!=0)
Out[106]: 
array([[ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [107]: (A!=0).cumsum(1)
Out[107]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 2, 2, 2]])

In [108]: (A!=0).cumsum(1).argmax(1)
Out[108]: array([3, 2, 1])
```

Finally, we use `fancy-indexing` to use those as the column indices to set appropriate elements in `A`.

In the second approach, when we use `argmax` on the boolean array, we simply got the first occurence of `True`, which we used on a row-flipped version of the input array. As such, we would have the last non-zero elem in the original order. Rest of the idea there, is the same.

Comment: could you explain the use of argmax ??

Comment: @DOKnow Added few comments on it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to explicitly form arrays with the row and column indices you want:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3,4], [5,6,7,0] , [8,9,0,0]])
row_inds = np.arange(A.shape[0])
col_inds = np.arange(A.shape[1])
nonzero_col_inds = (A > 0) * col_inds
max_nonzero_col_inds = np.max(nonzero_col_inds, 1)
A[row_inds, max_nonzero_col_inds] = 0
```