# Finding index by iterating over each row of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an numpy array 'A' of size `5000x10`. I also have another number `'Num'`. I want to apply the following to each row of A:

```
import numpy as np
np.max(np.where(Num > A[0,:]))
```

Is there a pythonic way than writing a for loop for above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `argmax` -

```
A.shape[1] - 1 - (Num > A)[:,::-1].argmax(1)
```

Alternatively with `cumsum` and `argmax` -

```
(Num > A).cumsum(1).argmax(1)
```

**Explanation :** With `np.max(np.where(..)`, we are basically looking to get the last occurrence of matches along each row on the comparison.

For the same, we can use `argmax`. But, `argmax` on a boolean array gives us the first occurrence and not the last one. So, one trick is to perform the comparison and flip the columns with `[:,::-1]` and then use `argmax`. The column indices are then subtracted by the number of cols in the array to make it trace back to the original order.

On the second approach, it's very similar to a [`related post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39959511/3293881) and therefore quoting from it :

One of the uses of argmax is to get ID of the first occurence of the max element along an axis in an array . So, we get the cumsum along the rows and get the first max ID, which represents the last non-zero elem. This is because cumsum on the leftover elements won't increase the sum value after that last non-zero element.

Comment: What does the following do: A[:,::-1]?

Comment: @Zanam Added some comments there.

Comment: I like the `cumsum` one :) interesting approach, and as usual, excellent explanation of both .